# Is it normal for my Handler output to be blank? If not, what can I look for to fix the issue?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I'm executing some ansible scripts, and have noticed that my handlers now show up as mostly blank:

```
RUNNING HANDLER [rest : make new rest folder] **********************************

RUNNING HANDLER [rest : untar new rest version] ********************************

RUNNING HANDLER [rest : remove rest package] ***********************************

RUNNING HANDLER [rest : remove previous rest folder] ***************************

RUNNING HANDLER [rest : symlinking new rest version] ***************************

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
host.abc.com : ok=38   changed=7    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

Looking through the box, it looks like these aren't actually getting ran... but the tasks themselves get ran fine. I have `-meta flush_handlers` at the bottom of my role `rest` -- should I be doing something different?

Comment: Can you show the ansible command you're using to run this?

Comment: `./ansible-playbook rest.yml -i inventory/rest -e env=dev`

Comment: Looks fine. Can you show the playbook/role/tasks where the handler is called? and the handler?

Comment: Note that `host.abs.com` is failed! Handlers are not executed for a failed host.

Answer (score 1):

I'll copy the answer from my comment:

> Note that host.abs.com is failed! Handlers are not executed for a failed host.